# Converting the Gregorian date to Jalali

Tags: php, date, calendar, jalali-calendar

The PHP code displays the date as 25 July 2023. I want this date to become jalali

```
$id = get_the_ID();

$date = get_post_meta($id, 'edgtf_match_date_meta', true);
$dateobj = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', $date);
$date = date_format($dateobj, 'j F Y ');
$time = get_post_meta($id, 'edgtf_match_time_meta', true); ?>

<span class="edgtf-match-date"> <?php echo esc_attr($date) ?>, <?php echo esc_attr($time) ?></span>
```

Comment: There is a [Jalali package](https://github.com/morilog/jalali) that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [IntlDateFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.intldateformatter.php) class.

```
$DateTime = new DateTime("2023-07-25");

$IntlDateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'ir_IR@calendar=persian',
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE, 
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    NULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL,
    "MMMM d, yyyy"
);

echo $IntlDateFormatter->format($DateTime);  //Mordad 3, 1402
```

For the date format see [ICU-Format](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#formatting-dates). "MMMM d, yyyy" is an example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't want to give the date manually. The date is taken from the WordPress post in the following code:
`$date = get_post_meta($id, 'edgtf_match_date_meta', true);`

Comment: The code you show is not reproducible for other programmers without your specific Wordpress environment. new DateTime creates a DateTime object. If I interpret your code correctly then $dateobj is just such a DateTime object which you can use instead of $DateTime.